iOS Universal Link only works from a few sources like Notes or Reminders
So I have everything set up:

https://pixquare.art/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
Added entitlement for applinks:pixquare.art and applinks:www.pixquare.art
My SwiftUI app handles the URL open with onOpenURL(perform:)

Everything works fine when I open a link from Notes or Reminders, but when I try the same link on Twitter, Messenger, or directly on Safari, it opens the webpage instead of the app.
What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks
